# Emails Not Working both Test and Actual Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

We got a new business unit

Couple of weeks when we sent out test emails, things worked.

But when we want to test them again today test emails are not working, The emails are not bouncing and nothing in the Not Sent report and in Send logs.

The error we are getting is
ExactTarget.OMM.UnverifiedFromEmailAddressException: From Email Address failed email address verification.
and attempt to use fall back from email address failed.
We have the domain verified aswell

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I would suggest a support case, there are to many variables here to troubleshoot

Comment: I logged the case and we got the error message from them

The error we are getting is ExactTarget.OMM.UnverifiedFromEmailAddressException: From Email Address failed email address verification. and attempt to use fall back from email address failed. We have the domain verified aswell